# Is re-email an actual word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I saw this sentence:

> The file has to be sent as a CSV file by re-email

Is this the proper way to say "send the file by replying to this email"?  I haven't found "re-email" in dictionaries, so I'm not sure.

Comment: To me "re-email" would mean to sent the original email again, not to reply to an other's email.

Comment: Hard to tell without context, but it does seem like one plausible interpretation (forwarded e-mail being another, as KillingTime points out), considering that most e-mail editors prepend replies with "Re:" which could, at least in theory, make someone refer to them as "re" mail.

Comment: The principal reason you won't find every valid *re-* word in a dictionary is becuase *re-* is a **productive prefix,** which can easily be used to form words with a predictable meaning -- as long as the meaning is the most obvious "repeat". Thus *re-email* would mean to send another email. I doubt that you can make *re-email* into a noun, though, which is what the preposition *by* requires.

Comment: Tnx @AndrewLeach, I also searched Google for any usage of 're-email' but found nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Resubmit" works much better.  Your example:

> The file must be resubmitted as a CSV.

[**Resubmit**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resubmit): Submit (something, such as a plan, application, or resignation) again (Oxford).

(Have you found *re-email* in a dictionary?  It's helpful if you do your due diligence before posting.)

Comment: Didn't find it, so I figured it might be a known form of speech until I saw most comments didn't understand the meaning :)
Thanks for the input

Comment: @Loves2Develop - your questions will be received better if you go ahead and explain in your question why you're not showing what you've found.  There are rather stringent requirements here.  // I'm glad you asked; I've wrestled with that question myself.  I've been quite happy with the solution I found.